# Why the test (null is Type) evaluates to false in Dart Language?

Tags: types, dart

Dart language [1.22.0 changelog](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#language-1) states:

> The Null type has been moved to the bottom of the type hierarchy. As
>   such, it is considered a subtype of every other type. The null literal
>   was always treated as a bottom type.

If Null is the bottom-type and null is the sole instance of the Null class, why the test `(null is B)` bellow evaluates to false?

```
class A {}
class B extends A{}

void main() {
  B b = new B();
  print(b is B); // true
  print(b is A); // b is A because B is subtype of A
  print(null is B); // false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `is` test is defined that way. For class types, it does a sub-class check, not a sub-type check.

It does that because its impractical to do an `is` check and still not know whether you can safely call a method on the object. It would mean that you would always have to do `if (x is Foo && x != null) x.fooMethod();`. So, the `is` check checks that the element has the checked type and isn't `null` (unless `null` is a subclass of the type)

What is really going on is that the types in Dart are (currently) all considered nullable. That is, when you write `int x;` you declare a variable that may hold either an `int` or `null`. In most places where you write a type, it's implicitly considered the nullable version of that type (that type or Null). The `is` test is an exception, where the type is considered itself only.

If Dart gets non-nullable types at some point in the future, you would have to write something like `int?` to get the nullable type and `int` to get the non-nullable version. At that point, you would be able to add `?` on the type of the `is` test test for the nullable type, or don't change and keep testing for the non-nullable type.